# Mixitup filter disappears and adds "fail" class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mixitup

In my mixitup, i am doing a basic filter but when i click one of the filter buttons, filtered items comes and disappears after a second. I can see in firebug, it adds “fail” class to the container of these items. But i can’t see what kind of error is that.

In codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPOgwr

Here is my HTML for filter buttons:

```
<div class="row row-centered filter-section">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-centered">
              <ul class="filter">
                <li><a href="#" data-filter="all">Hepsi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".basili">Basılı İş</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".kurumsal">Kurumsal Kimlik</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".ilan">İlan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".ambalaj">Ambalaj</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".stand">Stand</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">/</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".film">Film</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the container:

```
<div class="row grid" id="grid">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-bottom-30 mix basili">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <a href="" id="silver1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="isler/silver/silver1.jpg" alt="portfolio">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="portfolio-title text-center">
                    <h4 class="font-nixie">SILVER DÖKÜM DEMİR KATALOG</h4>

                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /overlay -->
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-bottom-30 mix basili">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <a href="" id="silver2">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="isler/silver/silver3.jpg" alt="portfolio">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="portfolio-title text-center">
                    <h4 class="font-nixie">SILVER DÖKÜM DEMİR KATALOG</h4>

                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /overlay -->
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-bottom-30 mix ilan">
            <div class="position-relative">
              <a href="" id="silver3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="isler/silver/silver4.jpg" alt="portfolio">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="portfolio-title text-center">
                    <h4 class="font-nixie">SILVER DÖKÜM DEMİR KATALOG</h4>

                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /overlay -->
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS code:

```
$('#grid').mixItUp();

  $('.filter-section').on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('#grid').mixItUp('filter', filterValue, false);
    $('#grid').on('mixFail', function(e, state){
      console.log(state);
    });
  });
```

I need your helps

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bit late to give you an answer on this, but I ran into a similar problem and as part of that I managed to sort yours, too.

To cut it short, your issue is that you applied the 'filter' class on the `<ul>` as well as the `<li>` tags. Removing the class from `<ul>` in the CodePen you provided solves the issue - although messes up your layout.

Hope this helps.